# C# - How to Remove extra characters of textbox (RFID)

Tags: c#

This is my code for reading rfid card to textbox, but my textbox have special characters how can i remove it?

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask] and [why you should not post imgaes of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 1):

Based loosely on exactly what you want to say, I would make use of REGEX to format (strip) the unwanted characters from DispString immediately after obtaining it from the RFID device and before sending it to your textbox.

I am no expert on regular expressions so I usually end up doing it the long way with a number of repalce statements e.g.

```
var newRFIDValue = DISPString.Replace(".","")
newRFIDValue = RFIDValue.Replace("x","")
```

etc.

Then finally invoking the display of the text.

It might require replacing hex characters or char rather than string characters but you can work that out.

Answer (score 0):

Regex.Replace( *YOURSTRING*, @"[^\d]", String.Empty )

can be solve your problem :)